# How to draw focus ring around NSBox on focus of child NSTextView in objective-c

Tags: cocoa, nstextview, nsbox, focusrect

I have one NSTextView within NSBox. I want to draw focus ring aroung NSBox whenever NSTextView got focus and remove focus ring as soon as NSTextView lost focus.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

To do this, create a subclass of NSTextView, and override the -becomeFirstResponder like so:

```
- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
{
    BOOL returnValue = [super becomeFirstResponder];
    if (returnValue) {
        //do something here when this becomes first responder
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

You can set up an [NSNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in the if statement above so that when that code block gets run, your view containing the NSBox can get called and subsequently draw a focus ring on the NSBox. To handle the NSTextView losing focus, you'll want to override -resignFirstResponder, like so:

```
- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder
{
    BOOL returnValue = [super resignFirstResponder];
    if(returnValue){
        //do something when resigns first responder

    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Be sure to change the class in interface builder, and change your class type in your header and/or implementation files to your new subclass of NSTextView:

[image]